# Daemonless multi-gibibyte-capable key-value store supporting synchronization?

Tags: synchronization, filesystems, store, key-value, nfs

I have a situation on a dynamically provisioned grid of servers that only share an NFS filesystem, and where I cannot reach a networked database.

Trying to avoid millions and millions of little files in the filesystem, I want to implement a few key-value stores. Can you **recommend a file-based key-value store that is able to synchronize access (gets/puts from these nodes) in an NFS-safe way?**

I expect each of these stores to have volume well into the dozens of gibibytes each.

Comment: Seems to be asking for the impossible. Synchronization across NFS is totally unreliable. NFS locking is slow, NFS performance without caching is slow, NFS performance with caching can't be synchronized. The only performant approach is to use an actual networked database protocol.